# RSpec expect HTTP error status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In this example, I create a project, then send a post to create another project with the same name. As it should, it raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique. I also want to check that it returns a 409 HTTP status, but since it raises the error, it automatically fails the test. How can I check that it returns a 409?

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Project Requests', type: :request do

  it 'Refuses duplicate projects' do
    project_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
    post '/projects', name: project_1.name
    expect(response.status).to eq(409)
  end
end
```

Here's the RSpec output:

```
Failures:

  1) Project Requests Refuses duplicate projects
     Failure/Error: post '/projects', name: project_1.name
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates     unique constraint "index_projects_on_name"
       DETAIL:  Key (name)=(Dr. Brain) already exists.
       : INSERT INTO "projects" ("name", "created_at",     "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

Below is my second approach. I expect the error, and that part works fine, but I can't check the status because it never gets to that line. (Notice how the puts command doesn't output anything in the RSpec results.)

```
# spec/requests/project_request_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Project Requests', type: :request do

  it 'Refuses duplicate projects' do
    project_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
    expect {
      response = post '/projects', name: project_1.name
      puts("This code is never executed because the line above fails")
      expect(response.status).to eq(409)
    }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
  end

end
```

Here's my RSpec output:

```
Project Requests
Puts should output text to the console.
  Refuses duplicate projects
```

That will pass no matter what error code it returns, so even though the test passes, it doesn't test what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

`response` is already provided for you by RSpec in the context of the example. Rather than assign the value returned from `post` to a new local variable, simply use the existing method:

```
it 'Refuses duplicate projects' do
  project_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
  expect { post '/projects', name: project_1.name }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
  expect(response.status).to eq(409)
end
```

Comment: The reason I included response= is because I got an error with the code above.
Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(409)
NoMethodError: undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass